# How do I extend a RAID1 array (PERC H330) with perccli?

Tags: linux, raid, dell-poweredge

I have RAID1. 1st of disks failed, I've replaced it and made it RAID comaptible. How can I add it to degraded RAID? I have access to OS (Ubuntu Server 18.04) with perccli installed. Here some helpful information about my case:

```
perccli /c0 show

TOPOLOGY :
========

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID1 Dgrd  N  111.25 GB dflt N  N   dflt N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID1 Dgrd  N  111.25 GB dflt N  N   dflt N      N  
 0 0   0   -        -   DRIVE Msng  -  111.25 GB -    -  -   -    -      N  
 0 0   1   32:1     1   DRIVE Onln  N  111.25 GB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

VD LIST :
=======

----------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC      Size Name   
----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID1 Dgrd  RW     No      NRWTD -   OFF 111.25 GB system 
----------------------------------------------------------------

PD LIST :
=======

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG      Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                 Sp 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
32:0      0 UGood -  111.25 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B KINGSTON SA400S37120G U  
32:1      1 Onln  0  111.25 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B KINGSTON SA400S37120G U  
32:2      2 JBOD  -   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2KB019T7   U  
32:3      3 JBOD  -   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2KB019T7   U  
32:4      4 JBOD  -   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2KB019T7   U  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried to add disk 32:0 to Virtual Disk  v0 in Controller c0:

```
perccli /c0/v0 start migrate type=RAID1 option=add drives=32:0
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Conversion to this Raid level is not possible.
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't want to **migrate** the raid Virtual Disk, which is about changing the RAID protection type/level (ie migrating from RAID1 to eg RAID0) and/or capacity.

Instead you want to start a **rebuild**.

Currently, one drive in your Raid1 array is reported as *missing* (state=Msng). So you need to affect the new drive to the disk group, and then use the rebuild command:

```
perccli /c0/s1 insert dg=0 array=0 row=0
perccli /c0/s1 start rebuild
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me.